# Primefaces bar chart always displayed as line chart

Tags: ajax, charts, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I wonder why Primefaces 5.3 bar chart always displayed as a line chart.

Please, any help as I couldn't figure why this behavior happen ?

Here is the bar char xhtml defined as p:chart type="bar" model="#{testBean.barModel}" id="testBarChartID" style="height:100px"

Here is the bean code.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "testBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean
{

private BarChartModel barModel;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    barModel = initBarModel();    
    barModel.setTitle("Bar Chart");
    barModel.setLegendPosition("ne");        
    Axis xAxis = barModel.getAxis(AxisType.X);
    xAxis.setLabel("Gender");

    Axis yAxis = barModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setLabel("Births");
    yAxis.setMin(0);
    yAxis.setMax(200);
}

   private BarChartModel initBarModel() {
    BarChartModel model = new BarChartModel();

    BarChartSeries boys = new BarChartSeries();
    boys.setLabel("Boys");
    boys.set("2004", 120);
    boys.set("2005", 100);
    boys.set("2006",200);
    boys.set("2007", 150);
    boys.set("2008", 25);

    BarChartSeries girls = new BarChartSeries();
    girls.setLabel("Girls");
    girls.set("2004", 52);
    girls.set("2005", 60);
    girls.set("2006", 190);
    girls.set("2007", 135);
    girls.set("2008", 200);

    model.addSeries(boys);
    model.addSeries(girls);

    return model;
}

public BarChartModel getBarModel() {
    return barModel;
}

public void setBarModel(BarChartModel barModel) {
    this.barModel = barModel;
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: <p:chart type="bar" model="#{testBean.barModel}" id="woSLABarChart"
    style="height:100px" />